# Android bound service onStart does not work

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a Service (Bound) which I am trying to start from my MainActivity.java. The below is my Main Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Handler m_handler;
    Runnable m_handlerTask ;
    private static ServiceConnection sConnection;
    static boolean  serviceBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DataDownloaderService.class);
        bindService(intent, sConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.NoActionBar);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            if (!Global.isMyServiceRunning(DataDownloaderService.class, this)) {
                sConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
                    @Override
                    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
                        DataDownloaderService.LocalBinder binder = (DataDownloaderService.LocalBinder) service;
                        Global.dService = binder.getService();
                        serviceBound = true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                        serviceBound = false;
                    }
                };
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex ){
            String p="";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        m_handler = new Handler();
        m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                RefreshNowPlaying();
                m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);

            }
        };
        m_handlerTask.run();           
        }
    }


    void RefreshNowPlaying(){
//Do something            
   }        
}
```

The service code is as shown below:

```
public class DataDownloaderService extends Service {

    private final IBinder dBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        DataDownloaderService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return DataDownloaderService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return dBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid){
        super.onStart(intent,startid);
        Global.DataDownloaderServiceStatus = "STARTED";
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        Global.DataDownloaderServiceStatus = "STOPPED";
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

I have also added the service to the AndroidManifest.xml under the Application element. However, I see that the service's onStart is never fired or the override onServiceConnected in the MainActivity is never called. I am new to Anrdoid development and Java. Can someone give me some pointers, please? I have noticed that the service's onCreate is getting hit, by putting breakpoints, but not onStart.

Answer (score 0):

`onStart()` will be called only if the service was started via context.startService(), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063826/why-is-onstart-is-not-called?lq=1).